# Identification http request AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, http, request

I haven't find solutions in other posts.
I am trying to access a database in a RESTful architecture.

That's why I want to send http request in angularJS.

Here is my code :

```
<html ng-app="countryApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Angular.js JSON Fetching Example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      var countryApp = angular.module('countryApp', []);
      countryApp.controller('CountryCtrl', function ($scope, $http){

          //$http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = "Basic " + myAuth._base64.encode("admin" + ":" + "changeit");

        // Simple GET request example:
          $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'http://localhost/db/coll'
          }).then(function successCallback(response) {
               $scope.countries = response.data;
               $scope.status = response.status;
               $scope.headers = response.headers;
               $scope.config = response.config;
               $scope.text = response.statusText;
            }, function errorCallback(response) {
               $scope.status = response.status;
               $scope.headers = response.headers;
               $scope.config = response.config;
               $scope.text = response.statusText;
            });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="CountryCtrl">
    <h2>Angular.js JSON Fetching Example</h2>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>JSON</th>
        <th>HTTP code</th>
        <th>Headers</th>
        <th>config</th>
        <th>textstatus</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>{{countries}}</td>
        <td>{{status}}</td>
         <td>{{headers}}</td>
          <td>{{config}}</td>
           <td>{{textStatus}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

I got a http error code : 401. It's normal cause I need to give login and password. I tried a lot of solutions find on the net successless.

How to send an http request with login and password in angularJS ?

Thank you

Comment: you are doing wrong in your success and error callback.`response.data` `response.status` ....... all these are giving array of values or response.data is giving array or show me the console of response

Comment: thanks for you comment, I didn't understand, I looked at the doc : https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.26/docs/api/ng/service/$http. These fields are in the returns. However I'm new in angularJS, and I maybe missed something.

Answer (score 0):

Add the parameters to the request you are sending:

```
$http({
   method: 'GET',
   url: 'http://localhost/db/coll',
   params: {login: login, password: password}
})
```

based on your angular version you can refer to: https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.26/docs/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: Without the line i got a 401 error code. When I add the line, I didn't receive any data, it shows {{countries}}  {{status}}  {{headers}}  {{config}}  {{textStatus}} ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this :
May be you want something like this

```
         $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'http://localhost/db/coll'
          }).then(function (response) {

               $scope.data = response.data;

            }, function (response) {
               // error callback
            });
      });
```

HTML

```
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>JSON</th>
        <th>HTTP code</th>
        <th>Headers</th>
        <th>config</th>
        <th>textstatus</th>
      </tr>
      <tr  ng-repeat="d in data">
        <td>{{d.countries}}</td>
        <td>{{d.status}}</td>
         <td>{{d.headers}}</td>
          <td>{{d.config}}</td>
           <td>{{d.textStatus}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```